# Creating new object for associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5

So I've been at this a while and have tried a bunch of different methods. Essentially I have an over-arching `property` model and an associated `deed` model. From the `properties#show view` I have it displaying all associated `deeds`. I have a button in my `property view` that displays a modal (using AJAX) to create a `deed` associated to said model. All the steps work (even 'edit' and 'update' using AJAX from the properties view) except when trying to save the `new deed` I get an error message:

```
This form contains 1 error. Property must exist
```

I've tried passing the `@properties.id` through in different ways and I just can't seem to get it. I'll list all the relevant info I have and if more is needed just let me know.

**Property Model**

```
class Property < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :deeds, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :deeds
end
```

**Deeds Model**

```
class Deed < ApplicationRecord 
  belongs_to :property
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :property
end
```

**Deeds Controller** (Included edit and update actions)

```
def new
  @deeds = Deed.new
  @deeds.build_property
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render 'new'}
    format.js
  end
end

def create
  @properties = Property.find(params[:deed][:property_id])
  @deeds = @properties.deeds.new(deed_params)
  if @deeds.save
    flash[:success] = "Deed created successfully!"
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to deeds_path }
      format.js
    end
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

def edit
  @deeds = Deed.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { @deeds.save }
    format.js
  end
end

def update
  @deeds = Deed.find(params[:id])
  @properties = Property.find(@deeds.property.id)
  @deeds.update_attributes(deed_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to deeds_path }
    format.js
  end
end

private

 def deed_params
   params.require(:deed).permit(:property_id, :deed_number, :deed_context, :consideration, :recorded_date, :grantor, :grantee, :trustee)
 end
```

**`new deeds` link from `properties#show` view**

```
<%= link_to fa_icon("plus", text: "Add Deed"), new_property_deed_path(@properties.id), remote: true, class: "btn btn-primary btn-large btn-ouline pull-right", locals: { property_id: @properties } %>
```

**`new.js.erb`**

```
$('#deeds-modal').modal("show");
$('#deeds-modal').html('<%= j render partial: "deeds/deeds_modal", locals: { property_id: @properties } %>');
```

**`_deeds_modal.html.erb partial` Form**

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <%= bootstrap_form_for(@deeds, layout: :horizontal, remote: true) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

      <%= f.hidden_field :property_id, value: property_id %>

      <%= f.text_field :deed_number, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.text_field :deed_context, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.text_field :consideration, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.text_field :recorded_date,     class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.text_field :grantor,    class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.text_field :grantee,  class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.text_field :trustee,  class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.form_group do %>
          <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
      <% end %>

  <% end %>
</div>
```

**server response upon `deeds_modal form` `POST`**

```
Started GET "/properties/99/deeds/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-05-30 
23:24:48 -0400
Processing by DeedsController#new as JS
  Parameters: {"property_id"=>"99"}
  Rendering deeds/new.js.erb
  Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered deeds/_deeds_modal.html.erb (5.6ms)
  Rendered deeds/new.js.erb (7.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 14ms (Views: 10.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started POST "/deeds" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-05-30 23:24:55 -0400
Processing by DeedsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"eaj9K...==", "deed"=>{"property_id"=>"", "deed_number"=>"69696969", "deed_context"=>"Bagel slaps", "consideration"=>"Considered", "recorded_date"=>"2017-05-31", "grantor"=>"", "grantee"=>"NipLips", "trustee"=>""}, "commit"=>"Save"}
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
  Rendering deeds/new.js.erb
  Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (0.7ms)
  Rendered deeds/_deeds_modal.html.erb (12.1ms)
  Rendered deeds/new.js.erb (20.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 32ms (Views: 30.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
```

So as you can see I've tried to pass through a local variable from the `new link` -> `new.js.erb` -> `deeds modal form` but I can't seem to pull the `property_id` into the `new deeds object`.

Is this even the correct approach for what I'm trying to do or am I just missing something? Hope this wasn't too long of a read and that I provided enough info... lol.

*Upon writing this post I clicked through some of the 'similar questions' on SO, which is where I got the `@properties = Property.find(params[:deed][:property_id])` line from but I still get `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Property with 'id'=):` upon submission. Also, thank you to anyone who takes the time to read this.

**`rails routes` Update (only included relevant routes for brevity)**

```
deeds GET    /deeds(.:format)                                      deeds#index
                   POST   /deeds(.:format)                                      deeds#create
          new_deed GET    /deeds/new(.:format)                                  deeds#new
         edit_deed GET    /deeds/:id/edit(.:format)                             deeds#edit
              deed GET    /deeds/:id(.:format)                                  deeds#show
                   PATCH  /deeds/:id(.:format)                                  deeds#update
                   PUT    /deeds/:id(.:format)                                  deeds#update
                   DELETE /deeds/:id(.:format)                                  deeds#destroy
...
property_deeds GET    /properties/:property_id/deeds(.:format)              deeds#index
                   POST   /properties/:property_id/deeds(.:format)              deeds#create
 new_property_deed GET    /properties/:property_id/deeds/new(.:format)          deeds#new
edit_property_deed GET    /properties/:property_id/deeds/:id/edit(.:format)     deeds#edit
     property_deed GET    /properties/:property_id/deeds/:id(.:format)          deeds#show
                   PATCH  /properties/:property_id/deeds/:id(.:format)          deeds#update
                   PUT    /properties/:property_id/deeds/:id(.:format)          deeds#update
                   DELETE /properties/:property_id/deeds/:id(.:format)          deeds#destroy
```

Comment: How do you set the `property_id ` in the `hidden_field`, can you check isn't `nil`?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not entirely sure how to check that in this situation, I'm still kind of new to rails, I'd assume it would involve a `.nil?` call somewhere but I'm not 100% sure where I'd place that in this process. However, I thought I was setting that by passing the local variable into the render call, so maybe thats what I'm missing?

Comment: Just go by parts, check the form and what's the value on the hidden input inspecting the source code.

Comment: you can clearly see here `Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"eaj9K...==", "deed"=>{"property_id"=>"",...` it is nil, you need to set it in `new`. please share your routes `rake routes`

Comment: try `<%= f.hidden_field :property_id, value: @deeds.property_id %>`

Comment: Yeah I knew `"deed"=>{"property_id"=>"",...` was empty but I thought @SebastiánPalma meant something else, my fault. Post edited with routes. and will try . @Farhans suggestion now.

Comment: Using `<%= f.hidden_field :property_id, value: @deeds.property_id %>`, `"deed"=>{"property_id"=>""...` is still nil.

Comment: check answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be you `new` action

```
def new
  @deeds = Deed.new
  @deeds.build_property
  @properties = Property.find_by_id(params[:property_id]) # add this line
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render 'new'}
    format.js
  end
end
```

**Update:**

If you are not using the `associated` property anywhere else, you don't need to pass the `locals` and I don't suggest `hidden_field` as it can be easily modified, alternately you can do..

```
def new
  @deeds = Property.find_by_id(params[:property_id]).deeds.new # add this line
  @deeds.build_property
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render 'new'}
    format.js
  end
end
```

Comment: Awesome! The `@properties = Property.find_by_id(params[:property_id])` was definitely the one I needed in the `new` action. Once added in combination with Sebastian's answer above, this worked perfectly!

Comment: glad it worked, please accept the answer since it helped.. :)

Answer (score 1):

As the error says `Property must exist`, so, your intention is to print the `property_id` for a new record, but for some reason that's not happening.

As that value goes from your `form_for` directly to create a new "deed", then in must be setted on it, you do it, but you don't check if it's printing something or not, and it get's you a `nil` value that's not allowed because of the relationship between Deeds and Properties.

When you send the form, you can see the value is empty:

```
"deed"=>{"property_id"=>""}
```

How do you define which `property_id` must a new record have? You can create a variable within your `new` method and set an object to print within your `form_for`, it'll give you a value to proceed with a new record.

When you make a request to the new method you pass through the params the value for `property_id`:

```
Processing by DeedsController#new as JS
Parameters: {"property_id"=>"99"}
```

So I suppose you could use it instead setting a local variable which hasn't been initialized, maybe you can try with:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :property_id, value: params[:property_id] %>
```

Comment: Thank you for the insight! Once I passed `value: params[:property_id]` in with the addition of the `@properties = ...` line below, everything worked!

Comment: @cdouble.bhuck well, you have to do either and not both...if you use `params[:propery_id]` you don't need to pass `@properties` locally..

Comment: Glad to help, just you could skip creating the variable in the controller to send it to the view, because is the same value "`params[:property_id]`" you receive in the `new` view.

Comment: Ahhh, I see, it does work without the `@properties` variable in the controller. However it doesn't work with _only_ the `@properties` in controller if I do not pass the `params[:property_id]` through. I have other things rendering on the `new modal` page that pull from the `:property_id` that work now, so is it okay to have both?

Comment: If you want to use `@properties` then, this should be your view for locals `locals: { property_id: @properties.id }` and `f.hidden_field :property_id, value: property_id`, However, I suggest to use it without `@properties` if you are not using it anywhere else, it will save you a db fetch else checkout updated answer

Comment: Cool, it does work as you suggested. The only thing is in that same modal I have `For <%= property_id.address1 %>, <%= property_id.address2 %>, <%= property_id.city %>, <%= property_id.state %>` so that way it displays the address for parent `property` of the `deed`, which doesn't work without the `@properties` in the deeds controller, and I don't know how else I would display that. But thanks for all your help!